# How to return base64 video via API

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I have videos that can be seen only if the user is authenticated. Due to which I decided to return videos in base64 format via API. However, I have quickly identified a problem, having noticed that if the file is greater than 1MB the returned data is truncated.

Example code:

```php
$size = Storage::size($video->path);
header("Content-length: $size");
echo base64_encode(Storage::get($video->path));
```

```html
<video :src="'getVideoSrc()" />
```

```js
getVideo() {
   this.axios.get('video/1').then(result => {
      this.video = result.data;
   });
},
getVideoSrc() {
   return "data:video/mp4;base64," + this.getVideo();
}
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Does playback start then halts? Did you hook up error handlers and other callbacks, what do they say? Which browser did you test this on? Firefox seems to allow unlimited data uri, Chrome limit is 2 MB, etc...

Comment: What's the reasoning behind base64 encoding on the server? You can request binary files via AJAX / Axios and use [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to transform the blob response into a temporary URL

Comment: Also, using method calls in your template is highly discouraged. Computed properties are much better suited for operations like this ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using base64 encoding as it's not required and only blows out the size of your data stream.

If you're happy delivering the entire video (as opposed to streaming it), you can use something like this client-side.

```html
<video :src="videoSrc">
```

```js
data: () => ({ videoSrc: '' }),
methods: {
  async getVideo() {
    const { data } = await axios.get('video/1', { responseType: 'blob' })
    this.videoSrc = URL.createObjectURL(data)
  }
}
beforeDestroy() {
  // clean up
  URL.revokeObjectURL(this.videoSrc)
}
```

FYI, I'm not sure what changes you'd need to make to your server-side but I imagine it would involve omitting `base64_encode()`